# Convert invalid isodate (5 digit for year) to valid date on mongodb (javascript)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this date on my mongo db

```
48603-01-01T03:17:12.000Z
```

When i convert this date  on converter websites

```
Results
Input   02/14/48603
Input (parsed)  Monday, February 14, 48603 12:00:00 AM UTC
Input (parsed, GMT) Monday, February 14, 48603 12:00:00 AM GMT
Result  1,471,599,100,800,000
Result (unformatted)    1471599100800000
Result (hex)    0x53a695da7ac00
```

i got this. Then i again convert to date after divin to 1000

```
    Input   1471629600720
Input (formatted)   1,471,629,600,720
Date (Etc/UTC)  Friday, August 19, 2016 6:00:00 PM UTC
Date (GMT)  Friday, August 19, 2016 6:00:00 PM GMT
Date (short/short format)   8/19/16 6:00 PM
```

In app, i multiply with 1000 for converting.

So, for fixing,  i have to first divide to 1000 after converting to miliseconds

```
    1471599100800000

/

1000 = 1471599100800
```

But i dont know what script should i write because it is 5 digit in a year, the functions is not working in chrome console:

```
    var myDate = new Date("48603-01-01T03:17:12");
var result = myDate.getTime();
console.log(result);
VM3347:3 NaN
undefined
var myDate = new Date("4863-01-01T03:17:12");
var result = myDate.getTime();
console.log(result);
VM3348:3 91294301832000
```

What are suggestions?

this worked

```
    var myDate = new Date("+048063-01-01T03:17:12");
var result = myDate.getTime();
console.log(result);
VM3405:3 1454554628232000
undefined
```

Comment: Why do you need a date to work that far in the future?

Comment: Change the input date string from `'486..` to `'+0486`. This works for me `new Date("+048603-02-14T03:17:12.000Z")`.

Comment: YEs it worked thank you

Comment: From [*wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601): "*An expanded year representation [±YYYYY] must have an agreed-upon number of extra year digits beyond the four-digit minimum, and it **must be prefixed with a + or − sign***" (my emphasis). ISO 8601 only allows years with more than 4 digits by agreement between the sender and receiver, so do this with caution.

Comment: but when i print it in mongo shell, output is `Mon Jan 01 48063 05:17:12 GMT+0200` i cant convert this to '+048603-02-14T03:17:12.000Z' format?

Comment: It is in UTC format. The default of JavaScript is to call the `.toString()` method on a variable evaluated. Instead call the `.toISOString()` method explicitly in order to see the UTC value. i.e `var d = new Date("+048603-02-14T03:17:12.000Z"); d.toISOString()`. See [`Date.prototype.toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)